# class passing reference to itself to a functor with accumulate

Tags: c++, stl, functor

I have a function that is descended from another class which in turn descends from a virtual base class.

Inside that function is a functor. The functor needs to be able to access all the objects inside of this function and its parent class. But, when passing a reference to "this" or to the function name, I get an error.

The reason for all this complication is to speed up the code. The algorithm I'm coding really only has one expensive part. My intent is to parallelize that part. However, that step accumulates over two values simultaneously, through several steps. So, I need to override some operators. A functor seemed like the easiest way to implement this.

The functor needs to be able to access objects in myClassA and myClassB, so I need to construct it with a reference to myClassB. (Since B descends from A, then all should be accesible.)

The problem is that when I try to pass the functor into the accumulate line, I get errors about no matching function.  I've tried "this", "*this", "myClassA", "myClassB", etc.

Any ideas??

```
class myBaseClass {
public:
    virtual double doFancyStuff(double a, double b)=0;
    virtual double doOtherFancyStuff(double a, double b)=0;
}

class myClassA : public myBaseClass { // B inherits a bunch of stuff from myClassA
    public:
        double doFancyStuff(double a, double b){
            double C = pow(a,b); //dummy action, is actually a lot of fancy math here
            return C;
        }
        virtual double doOtherFancyStuff(double a, double b)=0;     
}

class myClassB : public myClassA { // B inherits a bunch of stuff from myClassA
    public:
         double doOtherFancyStuff(double a, double b){
            return pow(a * b, 3);  //dummy action, is actually a lot of fancy math here
        }

    double doMoreFancyStuff(double a, double b){
        // do some stuff

        struct MyFunctor : public binary_function<Fraction, DoubleIterator, Fraction> {
            MyFunctor(myClassB& in_class, doubleA) : myClassA(in_class), column(iColumn) {} // Note: constructed with reference to myClassB, so it can access all the objects (functions, data) in myClassB                
            myClassB& myClassB;
            doubleA;
            double B = 123.456;

            double operator()(double B, double A, ) {
                double C = doFancyStuff(A,B);
                C += doOtherFancyStuff(A,B,C);
                return C;
            }
        }
        A = 1234 // actually result of some other work in the real code.
        //use stl to accumulate
        accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), temp, MyFunctor(this,  A) );  //Passing 'this' here so that functor gets a reference to myClassB
    }
```

Comment: This code is teeming with all kinds of errors. If this is C++03, then using a local class as a template argument is not valid.

Comment: I'm still very new to C++.  What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the functor outside the function.

Compilers not implementing the brand new C++11 standard does not allow templates like `accumulate` to be instantiated with a local class.